# How to make text editor wih bold, italic, etc formatter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I want to make flutter app which has a textfield who can be edited with format bold, italic, underline as shown in this picture 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKD04.png

is there a way to make this come true with flutter?

Comment: you need to access the clipboard if the user copied something, you need to have a state where you store the textfield input, the buttons, each button applies an efffect on the text, hope this gives you a clue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr). It's a package for "soft and gentle rich text editing for Flutter applications".

[image: 2]